# how to iterate over every item in items, search for corresponding member in members

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to create a function that will sort members so that they be in the same order as items. I need to iterate over every item in items, search for the corresponding member in members, and create a new member list. Then I need to call setMembers and pass the newly created member list.

```
function sortMemberList(items) {
const membersCopy = .slice(items);
membersCopy.sort((a, b) => a.dataset.id.localeCompare(b.dataset.id));
setMembers(membersCopy);
```

}

Comment: Did you mis-paste on `.slice`? You're not slicing anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could use .filter:

```
const filteredMembers = membersCopy.filter(member => member.property === value)
setMembers(filteredMembers)
```